# Can we delay the indices ILM transition in Elasticsearch for few busy hours?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ilm

As of now warm phase is set after 3 hours of index creation. But during busy hours, there is slow down of queries. And hence can we stop the transition for sometime, and restart after 8pm. But all indices should not start transition and replication at once, else there will be unstability in cluster

I checked for ilm start and stop, but this will start process for all indices at once.

Any cron or other solution? to balance and restart the process?

Comment: it's not clear what the slow down has to do with your proposal to halt ilm for a few hours?